# Have set Java to Path, but cant find the java command (Gitlab pipeline)

Tags: java, linux, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am tasked with creating pipelines in Gitlab the code is java with ant builds
I have set up JAVA_HOME set up ANT_HOME

echoed out the path, everything is correct, but I get the error java command not found

```
$ export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5"
$ export ANT_HOME="C:\Users\TonyCav\software\apache-ant-1.10.13"
$ export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
$ export PATH=$PATH:${ANT_HOME}/bin
$ echo "PATH ${PATH}"
PATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5/bin:/usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:C:\Users\TonyCav\software\apache-ant-1.10.13/bin
$ java -version
/bin/bash: line 145: java: command not found
```

is it because the gitlab runner cant see my path on my local c drive.
That I need to load it onto the gitrunner

Answer (score 0):

I was right. GitRunner Pipeline, could not access my home.
To fix it I used apt in Ubuntu.

```yaml
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y xvfb wget curl unzip gnupg -qq
  - apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk ant
  - java -version
  - ant -version
```